# “No sooner had I...” vs. “No sooner did I..."

Tags: grammar

What is the difference in meaning between the following sentences?

> 1. No sooner had I closed my eyes, I fell asleep.
> 2. No sooner did I close my eyes, I fell asleep.

Answer (score 3):

First, note that the correct and complete expression is **[no sooner ... than](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/no-sooner-than?q=no%20sooner%20...%20than)**. It is not necessary to use a comma to separate the two parts: **than** provides adequate separation. Your first example should therefore be written like this:

> No sooner had I closed my eyes **than** I fell asleep.

Your first example uses past perfect and past simple, which indicates that one event in the past preceded a second event in the past: in this case, closing eyes took place before falling asleep.

The second example uses past simple for both events, which indicates that both events took place in the past. The **no sooner than** construct makes the sequence clear.

Both are grammatically correct: use of past perfect is not necessary because the **no sooner... than** construct defines the order.  This [NGRAM](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=no%20sooner%20had%20I%2C%20no%20sooner%20did%20I&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cno%20sooner%20had%20I%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cno%20sooner%20did%20I%3B%2Cc0) indicates that both are common, and that the past perfect form is preferred.

Comment: Thanks, JavaLatte. Do you mean the two sentences have the same meaning?

Comment: Yes, in this context the meaning would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

> No sooner had I closed my eyes than I fell asleep.
>
> No sooner did I close my eyes than I fell asleep.

First off, I have put the conjunction "than" in place of the comma used in the original sentences.  The word sooner is a comparative adverb, so it should be followed by "than".

There's no difference in meening; you can use either the auxiliary had or did after the phrase "no sooner".  However, the use of the had is far more common and idiomatic.

Moreover, you can also use the phrase after the subject + auxiliary (had/did)  as follows:

> I had no sooner closed my eyes than I fell asleep.
>
> I did no sooner close my eyes than I fell asleep.

The use of the phrase "no sooner" in front position is more formal.